# R ggplot sorting issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a data frame, I have time of day as a string, so it can be anything from 23:59 to 0.00 (highest to lowest as imported). ggplot somehow does a sort on that column and plots "time" in a numeric order. Eg, 0:00, then 11:15, then 22:00, then 3:15, 4:30, etc.

I have tried the various methods of reordering but nothing seems to get the time as I would expect it, as in 0:00 to 23:59. I would like to plot the data as a histogram according to time but ggplot just doesn't like the time values.

Any guidance would be most welcome.

Output of newdf <- hm(df$Time)

```
> str(newdf)
Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  ..@ .Data : num [1:39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ year  : num [1:39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ month : num [1:39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ day   : num [1:39] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..@ hour  : num [1:39] 17 16 16 16 16 15 15 15 15 14 ...
  ..@ minute: num [1:39] 0 45 30 15 0 45 30 15 0 45 ...
```

Comment: You should convert the time to a date time class. It will make plotting much easier.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @jtr13, Thanks. I can convert the string 13/06/2021 23:45 to 2021-06-13 23:45:00 using POSIXct. I need to select a specific date, eg, 2021-06-12 out of lots of rows. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Right, I wish there were a time only class. However you can give them all the same date, as you've done and then format the tick mark labels with + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%H %M") or + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%I %M %p"), for either 24 hours or 12 hour time respectively. All the codes are available in the strptime help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest workaround would be to convert it into a decimal:

```
times<-as.numeric(gsub(":",".",times))
```

Now it will sort it in the right order.

```
times<-c("0:00","11:35","3:45","22:30")
sort(as.numeric(gsub(":",".",times)))
[1]  0.00  3.45 11.35 22.30
```

Note that this is not a GOOD workaround, as you will end up with weird gaps between times, because the distance between 1:45 and 2:00 is NOT the same as the one between 1.45 and 2.00. So if you're planning on displaying this on an interval axis, rather than just a nominal one, you'll need to convert into a date time class.
Or, actually you could use `hm()` from the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
sort(hm(times))
[1] "0S"         "3H 45M 0S"  "11H 35M 0S" "22H 30M 0S"
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the hm(time) to the data.frame as a test column, did a ggplot and it complained about "Removed 20 rows(s) containing missing values (geom_path)." When doing a str(df), I get a lot of extra data with that time value.

Comment: Hard to troubleshoot without more information. Can you run just `hm(time)` and identify what rows become NA?

Comment: I added the hm info to the original question. Easier to format.

Comment: can you share the ggplot code you're using (in simplified form) that generates this error?

Comment: The plot is done as:  ggplot(oldpv, aes(x=Yime, y=Units, group = 1)) + geom_line() + ylab("kWh") + xlab("Time of Day")
Warning message:
Removed 39 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path). (There are 39 rows in my sample date) ggplot plots nothing. 
Each of the Yime (Yime is not an error) values is a time value converted by hm. Yime[1] is 17H 0M 0S. The Time value is 17:00 which is a string.